# DrawPanelOptions onFeatureAdded

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin7, gwt-openlayers

We are working on our Gis application, I am using gwt-openlayers and we're creating Vaadin wrappers.

So I've extended the MapWidget and created the required layers and vector layers and added a DrawFeatureControl:

```
    DrawFeatureOptions drawFeatureOptions = new DrawFeatureOptions();
        private DrawFeature drawFeaturePoint = = new DrawFeature(vectorLayer, new PointHandler(), drawFeatureOptions);
```

and to catch the event:

```
    getWidget().getDrawFeatureOptions().onFeatureAdded(new () {
        @Override
        public void (com.openlayers.client.feature.VectorFeature vectorFeature) {
            Window.alert("Feature Added" + vectorFeature.getFID()); 
            serverRpc.featureAdded(buildVectorFeature(vectorFeature)); 
        }
    });
```

for some reason this is not working; although the following which should be almost the same is working fine:

```
    getWidget().getVectorLayer().addVectorFeatureSelectedListener(new () {
        @Override
        public void onFeatureSelected(FeatureSelectedEvent eventObject) { 
serverRpc.featureSelected(buildVectorFeature(eventObject.getVectorFeature())); 
        }
    });
```

using (addVectorFeatureAddedListener) on the vector layer will be fired everytime a Feature is added to the VectorLayer, and will not be fired when the DrawFeatureControl is used.
Can someone help me to catch the Features that are drawn using the DrawFeatureControl.

By The way I have a Cluster and BBox stratigies on the MapWidget, I don't know if this changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, for some reason

```
getDrawFeatureOptions().onFeatureAdded
```

doesn't do the trick, I had to inject the listener in GWT using:

```
getWidget().getDrawFeaturePoint().eventListeners.addListener(getWidget().getDrawFeaturePoint(), featurePointAddedlistener, EventType.VECTOR_FEATURE_ADDED, new EventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onHandle(EventObject eventObject) {
        FeatureAddedEvent e = new FeatureAddedEvent(eventObject);
        featurePointAddedlistener.onFeatureAdded(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that Vaadin have their own wrappers for OpenLayers to use OpenLayers in Vaadin ?

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/openlayers-wrapper

Comment: Yes, but it does not support Vaadin 7+.